# Copy Context Menu for ListView Control

Tags: wpf

What is the best way to add "copy to clipboard" functionality to a ListView control in WPF?

I tried adding an ApplicationCommands.Copy to either the ListView ContextMenu or the ListViewItem ContextMenu, but the command remains disabled.

Thanks,
Peter

Here is an xaml sample of one of my attempts...

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="SharedInstanceContextMenu" x:Shared="True">
        <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>            
    </ContextMenu>
 </Window.Resources>

 <ListBox Margin="12,233,225,68" Name="listBox1" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UpToSourceCategoryByCategoryId.Category}" ContextMenu="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=SharedInstanceContextMenu}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

How should I set the CommandTarget in this case?

Thanks,Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need a CommandBinding.

Here is how I would probably go about doing what you trying to do.

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding
        Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
        Executed="CopyCommandHandler"
        CanExecute="CanCopyExecuteHandler" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="SharedInstanceContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
    </ContextMenu>

    <Style x:Key="MyItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource SharedInstanceContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemContainerStyle}">
    <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Four</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to achieve this functionality via an attached property, as I described it on my [blog](http://jannsblog.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/copy-a-listview%E2%80%99s-items-to-the-clipboard/). The idea is to register the ApplicationCommands.Copy command with the ListView and, when the command is executed, read the values from the data bindings.

You'll find a downloadable sample on the blog entry, too.